# How to make changes reflect in many places when input is changed without ObserveEvent() in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have an input variable `input$shop_id`. Which is used to get data in server function using:

```
 observeEvent(input$shop_id,{id<<-input$shop_id})
`Data=dbGetQuery(connection_name,paste0("SELECT * FROM tab_name WHERE id_shop=",id"))`
```

That Data is further used to create dynamic UI using `selectInput()`

```
output$dependant=renderUI({
      selectInput("choice","Choose the Data you want to view",names(Data))
    })
```

I can't come up with the logic of the arrangement of these functions. I cannot get it to work. I have created a sample data and similar sample code for someone to try on:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui=fluidPage(
  column(6,uiOutput("shop_select")),
  column(6,uiOutput("cust_select")),
  column(6,uiOutput("select3")),
  column(12,offset=6,uiOutput("plot"))
)
server = function(input, output) {
  #sample data
  shopdata=data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),name=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")) 
  cdata=data.frame(id=c(123,465,6798,346,12341,45764,2358,67,457,5687,4562,23,12124,3453,12112),
                   name=c("sadf","porhg","wetgfjg","hwfhjh","yuigkug","syuif","rtyg","dygfjg","rturjh","kuser","zzsdfadf","jgjwer","jywe","jwehfhjh","kuwerg"),
                   shop=c(1,2,1,2,4,6,2,8,9,10,3,1,2,5,7),
                   bill_total=c(12341,123443,456433,234522,45645,23445,3456246,23522,22345,23345,23454,345734,23242,232456,345456),
                   crating=c(4,4.3,5,1.2,3.2,4,3.3,2.4,3.8,3,3.2,3.3,1.4,2.8,4.1))
    output$shop_select=renderUI({
    selectInput("shop_id","Shop ID",shopdata$id)
  })
    output$cust_select=renderUI({
      selectInput("cust_id","Customer ID",cdata$id,multiple = T)
    })
    output$select3=renderUI({
      a=input$shop_id
      selectInput("choice","Choose the Data you want to view",names(cdata))
    })
    output$plot=renderUI({
      renderPlot({
        require(input$choice)
        plotOutput(
      ggplot(cdata,aes(x=cust_id,y=input$choice))
    )})})
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

I know I am not clear on the question. Fixing the code which I posted is more than enough to clear my doubt. **Basically, I just need to know what is the logic when we have to use while using a `renderUI()` which is dependent on another `renderUI()`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set up a series of subsetting operations and then call `renderUI()`s on each subset, you will need to take advantage of Shiny's `reactive({})` expressions.

Reactive expressions are code chunks that produce variables and their magic is that they "watch" for any changes to their input data. So in your case one you select a `shop_id` in the first UI element, the reactive expression detects that and updates itself, automatically!

Here is an example showing the updating, just select different shop_id's and watch the available `cust_id`s change on the fly.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
ui=fluidPage(
    column(6,uiOutput("shop_select")),
    column(6,uiOutput("cust_select")),
    column(6,uiOutput("select3")),
    column(12,offset=6,tableOutput("plot"))
)
server = function(input, output) {
    #sample data
    shopdata=data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),name=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")) 
    cdata=data.frame(id=c(123,465,6798,346,12341,45764,2358,67,457,5687,4562,23,12124,3453,12112),
                     name=c("sadf","porhg","wetgfjg","hwfhjh","yuigkug","syuif","rtyg","dygfjg","rturjh","kuser","zzsdfadf","jgjwer","jywe","jwehfhjh","kuwerg"),
                     shop=c(1,2,1,2,4,6,2,8,9,10,3,1,2,5,7),
                     bill_total=c(12341,123443,456433,234522,45645,23445,3456246,23522,22345,23345,23454,345734,23242,232456,345456),
                     crating=c(4,4.3,5,1.2,3.2,4,3.3,2.4,3.8,3,3.2,3.3,1.4,2.8,4.1))


    output$shop_select=renderUI({
        selectInput("shop_id","Shop ID",shopdata$id)
    })

    cdata_reactive <- reactive({
        req(input$shop_id)
        filter(cdata, shop == input$shop_id)
    })

    output$cust_select=renderUI({
        selectInput("cust_id","Customer ID",cdata_reactive()$id, multiple = T)
    })
    output$select3=renderUI({
        selectInput("choice","Choose the Data you want to view",names(cdata_reactive()))
    })
    output$plot <- renderTable({
        filter(cdata_reactive(), id %in% input$cust_id) %>%
                                   .[input$choice]
                                     })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

1. A `renderUI` generates `UI` elements. Therefore it can only contain `ui` functions. You need to use it to generate the `plotOutput` and then use `renderPlot` separately to add content.
2. The names you assign in the `aes` call are the names of variables in the data frame you provided. Therefore `x` should be `id` not the values of `input$cust_id` (which must be called as `input$cust_id`, since it refers to an input object.
3. `input$choice` returns a string, not an object, so you can't use it normally in `aes` (recall that if this was a normal dataframe your aes would be `aes(x=id, y=choice)` not `aes(x='id', y='choice')`. Therefore, you need to use `aes_` with the `as.name` function to convert those strings into proper variable names.
4. What I think you want to do with `input$cust_id` is filter `cdata` to only include rows with the chosen `id` values. `dplyr::filter` is the best way to do that.
5. Finally, you're missing a `geom_*` in your ggplot call which is needed to actually render your data.

If you replace your `output$plot <- ...` call with the below code it should work the way I think you want it to:

```
output$plot=renderUI({
        plotOutput('plotout')
        })

output$plotout <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(dplyr::filter(cdata, id %in% input$cust_id),
           aes_(x=as.name('id'),y=as.name(input$choice))) +
        geom_point()
})
```

As for the question in your title, you only need to use `observeEvent` if you want to limit the code in the expression to only run when a specific trigger occurs. Any reactive expression (`reactive`, `observe`, `render_` etc.) will become invalidated and update itself if any reactive value (either a `reactiveValues` object or an `input$...`) changes. If you have an `input$` or a reactive value in a `render_` block, it will update if they change -- no `observeEvent` needed.